# Instaloader -How do I use the get followers/followees to get the full name of the user in addition to the user name?

Tags: python, web-scraping, instaloader

I use the below script all the time and it works great for the follower and followee lists. How can I also scrape the full name of the user if it is provided? I'm aware of '''property full_name''' but not sure how to use it in this context or if that would even work. I'm very new to coding and definitely not a developer. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import instaloader

loader = instaloader.Instaloader()

loader.login('myusername', 'mypassword')

profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(loader.context,'targetprofile')

profile = instaloader.Profile.from_username(loader.context,'targetprofile')

followers = profile.get_followers()

for follower in followers: print(follower, full_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead:

```
print(follower.username)
```